# Create one locale file for each component in Angular i18n

Tags: angular, internationalization

We are trying to find the best approach to work with text resouces, so that we could provide our translation files to our customers and they would be able to translate the texts, but with the `i18n` for Angular we just managed to create one single `messages` for for each locale, i.e: `messages.en.xlf`

Ist it possible to have `messages.component.en.xlf` or `messages.feature.en.xlf`?

Comment: AFAIK, no. But yo can just assemble the various XML files in a single one, and then build the app. This shouldn't betoo hard.

Comment: you mean other way round, one single in several. because the i18n generates one big file and I would need to create a chunk of those for each component. it's hard if you have several components.

Comment: Well, yes, after you've extracted the messages file, you need to split it in chunks. Once all the chunks are translated, before building the app for a given language, the chunks for this language must be assembled back in a single file passed to the angular compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Angular i18n Merge Files](https://github.com/marcioggs/ng-i18n-merge-files#readme).

Having the following file structure:

```
src/
└── app/
   ├── component-a/
   │   └── component-a.messages.en.xlf
   └── component-b/
       └── component-b.messages.en.xlf
```

You'd need to run:

```
npx ng-i18n-merge-files -f xlf
```

And the following file would be generated with the merged content of the previous files:

```
src/
└── locale/
    └── messages.en.xlf
```